# Как получить данные из формы?

Tags: php, html

```
<label for="step0-1" class="pick-item met">             
    <input class="pick-item__input" type="radio" name="step0" id="step0-1" value="металл"><span>металл</span>
</label>
<label for="step0-2" class="pick-item met">             
    <input class="pick-item__input" type="radio" name="step0" id="step0-2" value="дерево"><span>дерево</span>
</label>
<label for="step0-3" class="pick-item met">             
    <input class="pick-item__input" type="radio" name="step0" id="step0-3" value="пластик"><span>пластик</span>
</label>

<?php
    $step0 = stripcslashes($_POST['step0']);
    mail('mail@mail.ru', $subject, $step0, $headers);
?>
```

Как выбрать несколько `input` и получить в php?
Если поменять `radio` на `checkbox`, то отправляется только последний `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При чекбоксах надо поменять имена инпутам с `name="step0"` на `name="step0[]"` и  тогда в `$_POST['step0']` будет лежать массив

Comment: Добавил скобки в `name`, в php ничего не менял. Вообще ничего на почту не отправилось. Может что-то ещё нужно изменить?

Comment: конечно. раз `$_POST['step0']` это теперь массив то  и работать нужно соответствующе

Comment: Как их все вывести?

Comment: кого "их" и куда вывести?

Comment: Вот это получили массив `$step0 = stripcslashes($_POST['step0']);` не знаю в каком виде. `echo 
 ("$step0")` ничего не выводит

Comment: Потому что массив в `$_POST['step0']`, как я это написал, а не в `$step0`. Т.о. применяя строковую функцию `stripcslashes`  на массив получаем кукиш, логично

Comment: Теперь Array пишет

Comment: Ну да, это же массив. Ты же хотел получить то, что отметишь в чекбоксах. Вот, ты получил

Comment: Так вроде правильно, а нет `$step0 = var_dump($_POST['step0']);echo ("$step0")`

Comment: что, по-твоему, возвращает функция var_dump ?

Comment: весь массив. Или надо так `$step0 = $_POST['step0']; echo $step0[0] $step0[1] $step0[2];`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php#refsect1-function.var-dump-returnvalues    .......... я не вижу смысла давать мастер класс по работе с массивами и функциями в комментариях на SO. Вам стОит изучить основы языка программирования